# Unable to access websocket over Kubernetes ingress

Tags: spring, websocket, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have deployed two services to a Kubernetes Cluster on GCP:

One is a Spring Cloud Api Gateway implementation:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: api-gateway
spec:
  ports:
  - name: main
    port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: api-gateway
    tier: web
  type: NodePort
```

The other one is a backend chat service implementation which exposes a WebSocket at `/ws/` path.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
 name: chat-api
spec:
  ports:
  - name: main
    port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: chat
    tier: web
  type: NodePort
```

The API Gateway is exposed to internet through a [Contour Ingress Controller](https://github.com/heptio/contour):

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: api-gateway-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
    certmanager.k8s.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
spec:
  tls:
  - secretName: api-gateway-tls
    hosts:
    - api.mydomain.com.br
  rules:
  - host: api.mydomain.com.br
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: api-gateway
          servicePort: 80
```

The gateway routes incoming calls to `/chat/` path to the chat service on `/ws/`:

```
@Bean
public RouteLocator routes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
    return builder.routes()
            .route(r -> r.path("/chat/**")
                    .filters(f -> f.rewritePath("/chat/(?<segment>.*)", "/ws/(?<segment>.*)"))
                    .uri("ws://chat-api"))
            .build();
}
```

When I try to connect to the WebSocket through the gateway I get a 403 error:

`error: Unexpected server response: 403`

I even tried to connect using http, https, ws and wss but the error remains.

Anyone has a clue?

Comment: If you turn up the log verbosity on your `api-gateway`, is _it_ returning the 403, or is `chat-api` returning the 403, or is the ingress itself returning 403? You also didn't specify which ingress controller you are using.

Comment: Hello @MatthewLDaniel, thank you for your help. I am using Countour Ingress Controller, added that to the question. And I am unsure where the fault resides, can you send me some instructions on how to debug that? Thank you again

Comment: Are you familiar with [controlling Spring logging levels](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.4.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html)?

Comment: Separately, do you have [the access log turned on](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.4.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-embedded-web-servers.html#howto-configure-accesslogs) in your two apps? I would strongly suggest enabling that, too, so you can see more details about the requests cheaply that way, too

Comment: Oh, you are talking about spring logs, of course, I was thinking about something kubernetes related. I will lower the log level and add it to my question!

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel I can confirm that the request don't even hit the gateway, I believe it is being blocked by the ingress itself

Comment: ok, in that case, turn down the log level in Contour and see which rule it believes is violated and triage from there. Separately, it may go a long way to try `kubectl port-forward $the_pod 8080:8080` and ensure that the API plausibly could work at all, if you haven't already

Comment: any success in turning log level and finding violated rule?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue using Ingress resource with Contour 0.5.0 but I managed to solve it by
upgrading Contour to v0.6.0-beta.3 with IngressRoute  (be aware, though, that it's a beta version).

You can add an IngressRoute resource (crd) like this (remove your previous ingress resource):

```
#ingressroute.yaml
apiVersion: contour.heptio.com/v1beta1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: api-gateway-ingress
  namespace: default
spec:
  virtualhost:
    fqdn: api.mydomain.com.br
    tls:
      secretName: api-gateway-tls
  routes:
    - match: /
      services:
        - name: api-gateway
          port: 80
    - match: /chat
      enableWebsockets: true # Setting this to true enables websocket for all paths that match /chat
      services:
        - name: api-gateway
          port: 80
```

Then apply it

Websockets  will be authorized only on the `/chat` path.

See [here](https://github.com/heptio/contour/blob/master/docs/ingressroute.md#websocket-support) for more detail about Contour IngressRoute.

Comment: error: unable to recognize  no matches for kind "IngressRoute" in version "contour.heptio.com/v1beta1"